# Tring to Run LLMs Locally, but the Model was Stuck in the Generating Phase. How to fix it?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, mistral-7b

I'm using `transformers` to download and run Mistral-7B on my macOS with M1 chips.

Here is my code:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, LlamaTokenizer
import torch


tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2", padding_side="left")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2")

while True:
    # prompt = input("Input your prompt: ")
    prompt = 'What is YouTube?'

    input_ids = tokenizer.encode(tokenizer.eos_token + prompt, return_tensors="pt")
    
    print('generating response...')
    output = model.generate(input_ids, max_length=20, pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)

    decoded_output = tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

    print("Response: ", decoded_output)
```

My goal is pretty simple: Get a response from the LLM.

But when I ran this code, it stuck at the generating phase.

[image]

I have tried this code many times and waited tens of minutes, but it still stuck.

No response, even no error messages.

What can I do?

Thank you guys for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, no problem with this code. It's just too slow. It had taken about half an hour to get the result.

I should be patient next time.

Comment: Inference time on CPU is much slower than on GPU. So yeah, you have to wait.